# Fetching corrupted data from MySQL DB using PDO in php

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

This is my code in phpstorm.

`Fname` in MySQL database is a `varchar` field of `student` table which contains Persian characters. I set DB collation to UTF8, but still, this code returns me "??? ???" as result.

What is the problem in using it?

```
<?php
$conn = new PDO("mysql:host = localhost;dbname=university;charset = utf8","root","");
$query = "SELECT * FROM student WHERE status = 1";
$result = $conn->query($query);
while($row = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
    echo $row['Fname'],"<br>";
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
$conn = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=university;charset=utf8","root","",
                array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => "SET NAMES 'utf8'"));
```

instead of

```
$conn = new PDO("mysql:host = localhost;dbname=university;charset = utf8","root","");
```

Comment: this is the error "Call to a member function fetch() on a non-object"

Comment: @raminbadri change db name `test` into `university`. I have updated my answer too.

Comment: oh,i forgot that...and i also add this to my html tag: "<meta charset="utf-8";>"...now worked,ty

Comment: can you tell me what is wrong with my first code?!and why did not work?

Comment: @ramin_b you did not sent `SET NAMES 'utf8'` command to your database. You have to `SET NAMES 'utf8'` before query for utf8 characters. Please vote up my answer if you found it useful.